# how to split EEG signals data into training and testing?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, signal-processing

I have Psg signals as a dataset of sleeping records in edf format,  my CNN model consists on selecting an epoch of 30 s from each record and use a 1d convolutional on it, my question is how to split my dataset into  training, validation and testing if we know that my data are not CSV files but edf. thank you

Comment: It does not matter if it is EDF or CSV. In the end you import that data somehow and get a Numpy array that you can split. There are functions for the splitting,  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: https://medium.com/@contactsunny/how-to-split-your-dataset-to-train-and-test-datasets-using-scikit-learn-e7cf6eb5e0d

Comment: thank you for answering, the first step is to create epochs from our EEG signal and based on it we will split our data into training and testing is it possible with sikit learn